# Converting Antlr syntax tree into useful objects

Tags: java, antlr, execution, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm currently pondering how best to take an AST generated using Antlr and convert it into useful objects which I can use in my program.

The purpose of my grammar (apart from learning) is to create an executable (runtime interpretted) language.

For example, how would I take an attribute sub-tree and have a specific Attribute class instanciated.  E.g.

The following code in my language:

```
Print(message:"Hello stackoverflow")
```

would product the following AST:

[image]

My current line of thinking is that a factory class could read the tree, pull out the name (`message`), and type(`STRING`) value("`Hello stackoverflow`").  Now, knowing the type I could instanciate the correct class (e.g. A StringAttribute class) and pass in the required attribute data - the `name` and `value`.

The same approach could be used for a definition factory, pulling out the definition name (`Print`), instanciating the Print class, and then passing in the attributes generated from the attribute factory.

Things do get a bit more complicated with a more complicated program:

```
Program(args:[1,2,3,4,5])
{
    If(isTrue:IsInArray(array:{Program.args} value:5))
    {
        Then {
            Print(message:"5 is in the array")
        } Else {
            Print(message:"More complex " + "message")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

ANY/ALL help or thoughts are very welcome.  Many thanks.

Previous related questions by me (Could be useful):

1. [How do I make a tree
   parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061166/how-do-i-make-a-treeparser-in-antrl3/2061277#2061277)
2. [Solving LL recursion problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113703/antlr-left-recursive-problem/2117334#2117334)
3. [Antrl3 conditional tree rewrites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129569/antrl3-conditional-tree-rewrites/2136770#2136770)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend reading chapter 9, *Building High-Level Interpreters*, from [Language Implementation Patterns](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/tpdsl/language-implementation-patterns) by Terence Parr.

**EDIT**

Okay, to get you through the time waiting for that book, here's what you're (at least) going to need:

- a global memory space;
- function spaces (each function space will also have a (local) memory space);

and classes that spring to mind (in *UML-ish* style):

- `class Interpreter`

  - global : MemorySpace
  - functions : Stack<Function>
  - ...
- `class MemorySpace`

  - vars : Map<String, Object>
  - ...
- `class Function`

  - local: MemorySpace
  - execute(): void
  - ...

Comment: Thanks, I bought the book.  Should arrive in the next few days.  Hmm...stuck until then :|

Comment: Book arrived today.  Looks like the sort of stuff I need.  Many thanks for the recommendation

Answer (score 2):

Here's one with [ANTLR -> LLVM](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/LLVM):

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the AST, all you need is an iterator to walk the tree and the template to emit the objects you want.

Comment: Are you aware of any examples which explain this concept better?  Thanks

Comment: Yes, the ANTLR book has a chapter on templates and AST.

Answer (score 0):

This [Tutorial](http://gnuu.org/2009/09/18/writing-your-own-toy-compiler/) is based on Flex and Bison but at the end he details how he converts his AST to LLVM assembly code, it might be helpful.